# Named Entity Recognition on Upper Case Text

Tags: computational-linguistics, named-entity-recognition

How to extract entities from upper case text.

I use - http://corenlp.run/

with test data - I KNOW TOM LIVES IN LONDON.

LONDON - Location
TOM - not identified
relation not identified

with test data - I know Tom lives in London.
Tom - Person
London - Location
relation correctly identified.

How to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing *truecasing* first.

(There are various libs for that.  You will probably need to add a few domain-specific fixes for your data too.  And you should try smashing all case before truecasing.  It's not a completely solved problem either.)

As a general rule, breaking the problem down is the best approach.  Most of the components perform poorly when they are expected to do spelling correction and transliteration and truecasing and fix punctuation and ... Named-entity recognition is no exception.

There are examples where the caseless version is ambiguous.

> He helped Jack off the horse.

How you tune it and set the threshold will depend on your application.  (Do you prefer false positives to false negatives?)  Ideally the truecaser gives you a probability or other indication of ambiguity, but to do it perfectly requires full AI.